# No HDMI Audio with GeForce 9600GT and nForce board

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, alsa, hdmi

I've been trying to get HDMI with sound working for the last few days, and I'm a little bit out of ideas. *(I've verified that the hardware/Setup works via Windows.)*

`aplay` does not list my HDMI device:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've already compiled the alsa drivers (1.0.24) from a snapshot (with `--with-oss=no`) and added the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto    # Tried 3stack-dig and 6stack-dig too
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Still, the device does not show up.

If it is important, the HDMI TV is at the moment not configured to be part of the X session (I've tried that to, at least with X restart, and it didn't change anything).

What did I miss?

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: nVidia Corporation Device 07c3 (rev a2)
00:00.1 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a2)
00:01.0 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:01.1 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:01.2 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:01.3 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:01.4 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:01.5 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:01.6 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:02.0 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation nForce 630i memory controller (rev a1)
00:03.0 ISA bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP73 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:03.1 SMBus: nVidia Corporation MCP73 SMBus (rev a1)
00:03.2 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP73 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:03.4 RAM memory: nVidia Corporation MCP73 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:04.0 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation GeForce 7100/nForce 630i USB (rev a1)
00:04.1 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation MCP73 [nForce 630i] USB 2.0 Controller (EHCI) (rev a1)
00:08.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP73 IDE (rev a1)
00:09.0 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP73 High Definition Audio (rev a1)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1)
00:0d.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1)
00:0e.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation MCP73 IDE (rev a2)
00:0f.0 Ethernet controller: nVidia Corporation MCP73 Ethernet (rev a2)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] (rev a1)
```

```
$ aplay -L
default
pulse
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
front:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

**Edit:** In a forum thread I read that someone had problems with this chipset and kernel <= 2.6.36, so I'll try out Natty and report back.

**Edit2:** The card is still not recognized with Natty (2.6.38).

**Current state:**

The current state is that it did not work all the way up into the 3.x kernels. Quite some time ago I switched to a new nVidia card (GT640) which works flawlessly. As I don't intend to install the old card again, I've closed this question as not reproducible anymore. If you have this problem, too, feel free to open a new question with your technical details.

Comment: Look at the edited answer, I fixed it so you are not trying random numbers, but in stead using the real ones. I also added a manual in case it still doesn't works.

Comment: Considering you have a 9600GT I'd say that it doesn't have a HDMI audio device on it. what it DOES have is the hdmi audio piggyback function which requires you to connect a spdif cable from your onboard soundcard (the ALC spdif) to the graphics card. Do you have this cable?

Answer (score 2):

I have a GeForce too. Mine works with this trick:

1. Backup:

   `sudo cp /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/default.pa.backup`
2. Add one of this lines to the file (gksu /etc/pulse/default.pa):

   `load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,3`

   Where 1,3 is card#,device# for the nVidia HDMI output given by aplay -l.
3. Reboot
4. Go to

   `Menu > System > Preferences > Sound > Output` and choose HDA.
5. If it fails, you can try [this](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO_set_up_audio_over_HDMI_on_nVidia_GeForce/nForce_controller) manual

Comment: Unfortunately, if I add this line, pulseaudio refuses to start with a module load error. And as far as I can tell, this is only to tell pulseaudio what device to use...my problem is that the device is not even recognized by alsa.

Comment: The problem is...the output of `aplay -L` does not even list the device.

Comment: I will search and post here if I found something new ;-)